# Sublime Text 3: Ruby syntax highlighting bug

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

On 13th September Sublime released the first non beta version of Sublime Text 3.
I just did the upgrade and now I have issues with the "improved syntax highlighting" when I use Ruby.

```
def foo
    @bar / @baz
end
```

So if I want to divide instance variables the syntax highlighting breaks.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

[This](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/1142) pull request fixed the issue. Clone the [repo](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages) and move `/Packages/Ruby` to
`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`

After restarting Sublime the syntax issue is fixed!

Comment: search for a ruby package in Package Control.

Comment: this bug is being tracked at https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/1136

Comment: @KeithHall thank you! There is already a pull request that will fix the problem.

Comment: This was merged...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing a [Better Ruby](https://github.com/fnando/better-ruby-for-sublime-text). It Solved the problem for me.

Comment: The answer inside the question is better

Comment: Yes, that's the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 17.10 users: Clone the [repo](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages) using the instructions in the readme for Sublime (as Sepp stated), then just restart Sublime.